# date datediff without weekend how can it work with 2 different years

Tags: sql, datediff

I have also a problem with `datediff` without week end, if you can help me:
i try to find days between two dates and it's give the right result when the dates are in same year, but when the date change the year it goes wrong:
my code is:

```
convert (float,datediff(dd,departureDate, min(arrivalDate)) - 
    (isnull((datepart(wk, min(arrivalDate)) - 
    datepart(week,Event2024_actual))*2,0))) as arrivalhome
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
DATEDIFF(day, date_start, date_end) - ((DATEDIFF(day, date_start, date_end) / 7) * 2)
```